# How to make an app using SideMenu with react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native

After searching, i found that exists a lot of SideMenus already implemented, such as react-native-material-design side menu and react-native-elements. So what i want is to have a login screen in my app as the first page withou any menu and after the login, a screen with a header that contains the menu toggle button that shows or hides the side menu.

In the menu i want to have buttons that change my screens.

The problem is that i am using react-native-router-flux as my Router, and i can't find a tutorial that teaches how to integrate both. I can find a tutorial that teaches how to make de side menu with a static screen.

Anyone can give me a help? A very simple code showing the side menu component and just two splash screens and how i can change the screens through my router, would be awesome!

Comment: Does your problem solved or not yet?

Comment: Yes, I understood how it works and now I am already using the v4